# vimrc split bar movable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, vim-plugin

I took my vimrc from a friend and it has some changes to the split bar. How do I restore it to the default split bar?

my `.vim` folder: [here](http://124.124.247.3:8000/static/vim.tar.gz)

and .vimrc:

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Maintainer: amix the lucky stiff
"             http://amix.dk - amix@amix.dk
"
" Version: 3.6 - 25/08/10 14:40:30
"
" Blog_post: 
"       http://amix.dk/blog/post/19486#The-ultimate-vim-configuration-vimrc
" Syntax_highlighted:
"       http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.html
" Raw_version: 
"       http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.txt
"
" How_to_Install_on_Unix:
"    $ mkdir ~/.vim_runtime
"    $ svn co svn://orangoo.com/vim ~/.vim_runtime
"    $ cat ~/.vim_runtime/install.sh
"    $ sh ~/.vim_runtime/install.sh <system>
"      <sytem> can be `mac`, `linux` or `windows`
"
" How_to_Upgrade:
"    $ svn update ~/.vim_runtime
"
" Sections:
"    -> General
"    -> VIM user interface
"    -> Colors and Fonts
"    -> Files and backups
"    -> Text, tab and indent related
"    -> Visual mode related
"    -> Command mode related
"    -> Moving around, tabs and buffers
"    -> Statusline
"    -> Parenthesis/bracket expanding
"    -> General Abbrevs
"    -> Editing mappings
"
"    -> Cope
"    -> Minibuffer plugin
"    -> Omni complete functions
"    -> Python section
"    -> JavaScript section
"
"
" Plugins_Included:
"     > minibufexpl.vim - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159
"       Makes it easy to get an overview of buffers:
"           info -> :e ~/.vim_runtime/plugin/minibufexpl.vim
"
"     > bufexplorer - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42
"       Makes it easy to switch between buffers:
"           info -> :help bufExplorer
"
"     > yankring.vim - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1234
"       Emacs's killring, useful when using the clipboard:
"           info -> :help yankring
"
"     > surround.vim - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697
"       Makes it easy to work with surrounding text:
"           info -> :help surround
"
"     > snipMate.vim - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540
"       Snippets for many languages (similar to TextMate's):
"           info -> :help snipMate
"
"     > mru.vim - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=521
"       Plugin to manage Most Recently Used (MRU) files:
"           info -> :e ~/.vim_runtime/plugin/mru.vim
"
"     > Command-T - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025
"       Command-T plug-in provides an extremely fast, intuitive mechanism for opening filesa:
"           info -> :help CommandT
"           screencast and web-help -> http://amix.dk/blog/post/19501
"
"
"  Revisions:
"     > 3.6: Added lots of stuff (colors, Command-T, Vim 7.3 persistent undo etc.)
"     > 3.5: Paste mode is now shown in status line  if you are in paste mode
"     > 3.4: Added mru.vim
"     > 3.3: Added syntax highlighting for Mako mako.vim 
"     > 3.2: Turned on python_highlight_all for better syntax
"            highlighting for Python
"     > 3.1: Added revisions ;) and bufexplorer.vim
"
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => General
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Sets how many lines of history VIM has to remember
set history=700

" Enable filetype plugin
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
set nocp

" Set to auto read when a file is changed from the outside
set autoread

" With a map leader it's possible to do extra key combinations
" like <leader>w saves the current file
let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","

" Fast saving
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>

" Fast editing of the .vimrc
map <leader>e :e! ~/.vim_runtime/vimrc<cr>

" When vimrc is edited, reload it
autocmd! bufwritepost vimrc source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrc


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => VIM user interface
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Set 7 lines to the curors - when moving vertical..
set so=7

set wildmenu "Turn on WiLd menu

set ruler "Always show current position

set cmdheight=2 "The commandbar height

set hid "Change buffer - without saving

" Set backspace config
set backspace=eol,start,indent
set whichwrap+=<,>,h,l

set ignorecase "Ignore case when searching
set smartcase

set hlsearch "Highlight search things

set incsearch "Make search act like search in modern browsers
set nolazyredraw "Don't redraw while executing macros 

set magic "Set magic on, for regular expressions

set showmatch "Show matching bracets when text indicator is over them
set mat=2 "How many tenths of a second to blink

" No sound on errors
set noerrorbells
set novisualbell
set t_vb=
set tm=500


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Colors and Fonts
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
syntax enable "Enable syntax hl

colorscheme 256-jungle


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Files, backups and undo
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Turn backup off, since most stuff is in SVN, git anyway...
set nobackup
set nowb
set noswapfile

"Persistent undo
try
    if MySys() == "windows"
      set undodir=C:\Windows\Temp
    else
      set undodir=~/.vim_runtime/undodir
    endif

    set undofile
catch
endtry


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Text, tab and indent related
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set smarttab

set lbr
set tw=500

set ai "Auto indent
set si "Smart indet
set wrap "Wrap lines


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Visual mode related
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Really useful!
"  In visual mode when you press * or # to search for the current selection
vnoremap <silent> * :call VisualSearch('f')<CR>
vnoremap <silent> # :call VisualSearch('b')<CR>

" When you press gv you vimgrep after the selected text
vnoremap <silent> gv :call VisualSearch('gv')<CR>
map <leader>g :vimgrep // **/*.<left><left><left><left><left><left><left>


function! CmdLine(str)
    exe "menu Foo.Bar :" . a:str
    emenu Foo.Bar
    unmenu Foo
endfunction

" From an idea by Michael Naumann
function! VisualSearch(direction) range
    let l:saved_reg = @"
    execute "normal! vgvy"

    let l:pattern = escape(@", '\\/.*$^~[]')
    let l:pattern = substitute(l:pattern, "\n$", "", "")

    if a:direction == 'b'
        execute "normal ?" . l:pattern . "^M"
    elseif a:direction == 'gv'
        call CmdLine("vimgrep " . '/'. l:pattern . '/' . ' **/*.')
    elseif a:direction == 'f'
        execute "normal /" . l:pattern . "^M"
    endif

    let @/ = l:pattern
    let @" = l:saved_reg
endfunction



"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Command mode related
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Smart mappings on the command line
cno $h e ~/
cno $d e ~/Desktop/
cno $j e ./
cno $c e <C-\>eCurrentFileDir("e")<cr>

" $q is super useful when browsing on the command line
cno $q <C-\>eDeleteTillSlash()<cr>

" Bash like keys for the command line
cnoremap <C-A>      <Home>
cnoremap <C-E>      <End>
cnoremap <C-K>      <C-U>

cnoremap <C-P> <Up>
cnoremap <C-N> <Down>

" Useful on some European keyboards
map ½ $
imap ½ $
vmap ½ $
cmap ½ $


func! Cwd()
  let cwd = getcwd()
  return "e " . cwd 
endfunc

func! DeleteTillSlash()
  let g:cmd = getcmdline()
  if MySys() == "linux" || MySys() == "mac"
    let g:cmd_edited = substitute(g:cmd, "\\(.*\[/\]\\).*", "\\1", "")
  else
    let g:cmd_edited = substitute(g:cmd, "\\(.*\[\\\\]\\).*", "\\1", "")
  endif
  if g:cmd == g:cmd_edited
    if MySys() == "linux" || MySys() == "mac"
      let g:cmd_edited = substitute(g:cmd, "\\(.*\[/\]\\).*/", "\\1", "")
    else
      let g:cmd_edited = substitute(g:cmd, "\\(.*\[\\\\\]\\).*\[\\\\\]", "\\1", "")
    endif
  endif
  return g:cmd_edited
endfunc

func! CurrentFileDir(cmd)
  return a:cmd . " " . expand("%:p:h") . "/"
endfunc


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Moving around, tabs and buffers
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Map space to / (search) and c-space to ? (backgwards search)
map <space> /
map <c-space> ?
map <silent> <leader><cr> :noh<cr>

" Smart way to move btw. windows
map <C-j> <C-W>j
map <C-k> <C-W>k
map <C-h> <C-W>h
map <C-l> <C-W>l

" Close the current buffer
map <leader>bd :Bclose<cr>

" Close all the buffers
map <leader>ba :1,300 bd!<cr>

" Use the arrows to something usefull
map <right> :bn<cr>
map <left> :bp<cr>

" Tab configuration
map <leader>tn :tabnew<cr>
map <leader>te :tabedit
map <leader>tc :tabclose<cr>
map <leader>tm :tabmove

" When pressing <leader>cd switch to the directory of the open buffer
map <leader>cd :cd %:p:h<cr>


command! Bclose call <SID>BufcloseCloseIt()
function! <SID>BufcloseCloseIt()
   let l:currentBufNum = bufnr("%")
   let l:alternateBufNum = bufnr("#")

   if buflisted(l:alternateBufNum)
     buffer #
   else
     bnext
   endif

   if bufnr("%") == l:currentBufNum
     new
   endif

   if buflisted(l:currentBufNum)
     execute("bdelete! ".l:currentBufNum)
   endif
endfunction

" Specify the behavior when switching between buffers 
try
  set switchbuf=usetab
  set stal=2
catch
endtry


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Statusline
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Always hide the statusline
set laststatus=2

" Format the statusline
set statusline=\ %{HasPaste()}%F%m%r%h\ %w\ \ CWD:\ %r%{CurDir()}%h\ \ \ Line:\ %l/%L:%c


function! CurDir()
    let curdir = substitute(getcwd(), '/Users/amir/', "~/", "g")
    return curdir
endfunction

function! HasPaste()
    if &paste
        return 'PASTE MODE  '
    else
        return ''
    endif
endfunction


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Parenthesis/bracket expanding
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
vnoremap $1 <esc>`>a)<esc>`<i(<esc>
vnoremap $2 <esc>`>a]<esc>`<i[<esc>
vnoremap $3 <esc>`>a}<esc>`<i{<esc>
vnoremap $$ <esc>`>a"<esc>`<i"<esc>
vnoremap $q <esc>`>a'<esc>`<i'<esc>
vnoremap $e <esc>`>a"<esc>`<i"<esc>

" Map auto complete of (, ", ', [
inoremap $1 ()<esc>i
inoremap $2 []<esc>i
inoremap $3 {}<esc>i
inoremap $4 {<esc>o}<esc>O
inoremap $q ''<esc>i
inoremap $e ""<esc>i
inoremap $t <><esc>i


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => General Abbrevs
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
iab xdate <c-r>=strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")<cr>


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Editing mappings
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"Remap VIM 0
map 0 ^

"Move a line of text using ALT+[jk] or Comamnd+[jk] on mac
nmap <M-j> mz:m+<cr>`z
nmap <M-k> mz:m-2<cr>`z
vmap <M-j> :m'>+<cr>`<my`>mzgv`yo`z
vmap <M-k> :m'<-2<cr>`>my`<mzgv`yo`z


"Delete trailing white space, useful for Python ;)
func! DeleteTrailingWS()
  exe "normal mz"
  %s/\s\+$//ge
  exe "normal `z"
endfunc
autocmd BufWrite *.py :call DeleteTrailingWS()

set guitablabel=%t


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Cope
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Do :help cope if you are unsure what cope is. It's super useful!
map <leader>cc :botright cope<cr>
map <leader>n :cn<cr>
map <leader>p :cp<cr>


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => bufExplorer plugin
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let g:bufExplorerDefaultHelp=0
let g:bufExplorerShowRelativePath=1
map <leader>o :BufExplorer<cr>


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Minibuffer plugin
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let g:miniBufExplModSelTarget = 1
let g:miniBufExplorerMoreThanOne = 2
let g:miniBufExplModSelTarget = 0
let g:miniBufExplUseSingleClick = 1
let g:miniBufExplMapWindowNavVim = 1
let g:miniBufExplVSplit = 25
let g:miniBufExplSplitBelow=1

let g:bufExplorerSortBy = "name"

autocmd BufRead,BufNew :call UMiniBufExplorer

map <leader>u :TMiniBufExplorer<cr>


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Omni complete functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Spell checking
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"Pressing ,ss will toggle and untoggle spell checking
map <leader>ss :setlocal spell!<cr>

"Shortcuts using <leader>
map <leader>sn ]s
map <leader>sp [s
map <leader>sa zg
map <leader>s? z=


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Python section
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let python_highlight_all = 1
au FileType python syn keyword pythonDecorator True None False self

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.jinja set syntax=htmljinja
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.mako set ft=mako

au FileType python inoremap <buffer> $r return
au FileType python inoremap <buffer> $i import
au FileType python inoremap <buffer> $p print
au FileType python inoremap <buffer> $f #--- PH ----------------------------------------------<esc>FP2xi
au FileType python map <buffer> <leader>1 /class
au FileType python map <buffer> <leader>2 /def
au FileType python map <buffer> <leader>C ?class
au FileType python map <buffer> <leader>D ?def


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => JavaScript section
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
au FileType javascript call JavaScriptFold()
au FileType javascript setl fen
au FileType javascript setl nocindent

au FileType javascript imap <c-t> AJS.log();<esc>hi
au FileType javascript imap <c-a> alert();<esc>hi

au FileType javascript inoremap <buffer> $r return
au FileType javascript inoremap <buffer> $f //--- PH ----------------------------------------------<esc>FP2xi

function! JavaScriptFold()
    setl foldmethod=syntax
    setl foldlevelstart=1
    syn region foldBraces start=/{/ end=/}/ transparent fold keepend extend

    function! FoldText()
    return substitute(getline(v:foldstart), '{.*', '{...}', '')
    endfunction
    setl foldtext=FoldText()
endfunction


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => MRU plugin
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let MRU_Max_Entries = 400
map <leader>f :MRU<CR>


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Command-T
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let g:CommandTMaxHeight = 15
set wildignore+=*.o,*.obj,.git,*.pyc
noremap <leader>j :CommandT<cr>
noremap <leader>y :CommandTFlush<cr>


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Vim grep
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let Grep_Skip_Dirs = 'RCS CVS SCCS .svn generated'
set grepprg=/bin/grep\ -nH



"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => MISC
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Remove the Windows ^M - when the encodings gets messed up
noremap <Leader>m mmHmt:%s/<C-V><cr>//ge<cr>'tzt'm

"Quickly open a buffer for scripbble
map <leader>q :e ~/buffer<cr>
au BufRead,BufNewFile ~/buffer iab <buffer> xh1 ===========================================

map <leader>pp :setlocal paste!<cr>

map <leader>bb :cd ..<cr>
"setting taglist to be opened at startup
let Tlist_Auto_Open = 1
"mapping keys for auto changing the colorscheme
map <silent><F3> :NEXTCOLOR<cr>
map <silent><F2> :PREVCOLOR<cr>

"to get function parameters shown from autocomplpop
let g:AutoComplPop_CompleteoptPreview = 1
"mapping key to save all the  open buffers
map <silent><F4> :wa<cr>
```

[image: It shows it like this]

the split bar shows like in the image. While I want it to be movable. What needs to be changed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can move the horizontal split bar by pressing `control-w` follow by `10+` to increase the size of the active window by 10 lines in the vertical directions. (or `-` to decrease), e.g. move the ruler up or down.

The resize the vertical split bar, you can do something similar: `control-w 10>` or `<`. To move the split bar to the left or right.

I don't think this is related to the `.vimrc` that you give.

Comment: :he minwidth and :he minheight